# Error with Fork and NodeJS

Tags: c, node.js, exec, fork

I'm trying to use NodeJS with a C program to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setvbuf for JS files using Fork().

My program.c :

```
int readTabStr(int k)
{
char * tabString[] = {"p1.js","p2.js","p3.js","p4.js"};
int taille = sizeof(tabString)/sizeof(char);
int i;
    for(i=0; i<taille; i++)
    {
        if (fork() == 0)
        {
            execlp("node","node", tabString[i], NULL);
        }
        else
        {
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

I'm using this JS file to launch the C file:

```
var FFI = require("../../lib/ffi");

var test = new FFI.Library("./readTab", {
"readTabStr": ["int", ["int" ]]  
});

var resultat = test.readTabStr(0);
```

The problem is that after executing the p1.js, p2.js, p3.jsn p4.js. I get 4 error messages :

> ```
> node.js:116
> throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
> ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module '/home/fighter/Documents/ffi/kerrighed/execlp/��$[]�U
> `enter code here`��E��E��U��S������1�'
> at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:299:11)
> at Function._load (module.js:245:25)
> at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:402:10)
> at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:108:26)
> ```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can accept your own answer as the (only) correct one by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved,

The problem was

```
 int taille = sizeof(tabString)/sizeof(char);
```

I should do :

```
int taille = sizeof(tabString)/sizeof(char*);
```

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Related to your just removed question: see http://jsfiddle.net/Lepfsm9r/1/. Not sure if it is any good, but probably will give you some jump-start.

Comment: I also met some haters today, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790761/how-to-replace-only-the-last-match-of-a-string-with-preg-replace/51020307#51020307) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025302/python-regex-match-char-between-two-chars-with-anything-before-or-after-the-m/51025516#51025516). Don't give up :)