# How to replace only the last match of a string with preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I have to replace the last match of a string (for example the word foo) in HTML document. The problem is that the structure of the HTML document is always random.

I'm trying to accomplish that with preg_replace, but so far I know how to replace only the first match, but not the last one.

Thanks.

Comment: please show an example and also please see [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: if you know how to replace the last match, jou can just simple reverse the string, replace, and reverse again ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use negative look after `(?!...)`

```
$str = 'text abcd text text efgh';
echo preg_replace('~text(?!.*text)~', 'bar', $str),"\n";
```

**output:**

```
text abcd text bar efgh
```

Comment: @AhmetErkanÇELİK: Just add `(?s)` at the beginning of the regex.

Answer (score 6):

A common approach to match all text to the last occurrence of the subsequent pattern(s) is using a *greedy dot*, `.*`. So, you may match and capture the text before the last `text` and replace with a backreference + the new value:

```
$str = 'text abcd text text efgh';
echo preg_replace('~(.*)text~su', '${1}bar', $str);
// => text abcd text bar efgh
```

If `text` is some value inside a variable that must be treated as plain text, use `preg_quote` to [ensure all special chars are escaped correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531456/is-there-a-php-function-that-can-escape-regex-patterns-before-they-are-applied):

```
preg_replace('~(.*)' . preg_quote($text, '~') . '~su', '${1}bar', $str)
```

See the [**online PHP demo**](https://ideone.com/UaQQyx) and a [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/4eNhLr/1).

Here, `(.*)` matches and *captures* into Group 1 any zero or more chars (note that the `s` modifier makes the dot match line break chars, too), as many as possible, up to the rightmost (last) occurrence of `text`. If `text` is a Unicode substring, the `u` modifier comes handy in PHP (it enables `(*UTF)` PCRE verb allowing parsing the incoming string as a sequence of Unicode code points rather than bytes and the `(*UCP)` verb that makes all shorthand character classes Unicode aware - if any).

The `${1}` is a replacement backreference, a placeholder holding the value captured into Group 1 that lets restore that substring inside the resulting string. You can use `$1`, but a [problem might arise if the `$text` starts with a digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027811/preg-replace-add-number-after-backreference).

Comment: This necropost is necessary because prior answers suboptimal, incomplete, or incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

An example

```
<?php

$str = 'Some random text';
$str_Pattern = '/[^ ]*$/';

preg_match($str_Pattern, $str, $results);

print $results[0];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course the accepted solution given here is correct. Nevertheless you might also want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3835653/7424979) post. I'm using this where no pattern is needed and the string does not contain characters that could not be captured by the functions used (i.e. multibyte ones). I also put an additional parameter for dis/regarding case.

The first line then is:

```
$pos = $case === true ? strripos($subject, $search) : strrpos($subject, $search);
```

I have to admit that I did not test the performance. However, I guess that *preg_replace()* is slower, specially on large strings.