# Replace last slash in string php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a hard time getting around regular expressions and I'm trying to remove the last forward slash in a string :

```
$public_url = "https://api.mongohq.com/";
```

What I intend is remove the last forward slash and replace it with something else. I figured I could use `preg_replace` but I cannot find the right pattern for doing it.

Comment: rtrim($public_url,'/'); [http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

Comment: @JonHulka ~ I was looking for a regex so I can replace with something rather than adding at the end of string :)

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."

Comment: @nkr ~ you're right :)) I never had the time to sit and learn RegEx :| I hope I will soon though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a negative lookafter-expression:

```
<?php
$public_url = "https://api.mongohq.com/";
$replace = "foobar";

echo preg_replace("~\/(?!.*\/)~", $replace, $public_url);
?>
```

Output:
    https://api.mongohq.comfoobar

**Update:**
Use the following regex to avoid problems with characters behind the last slash:

```
echo preg_replace("~\/(?!.*\/)(.*)~", $replace, $public_url);
```

All characters behind the last slash are replaced, too. Thanks to knittl!

Comment: BTW: The question was already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790761/how-to-replace-only-the-last-match-of-a-string-with-preg-replace?rq=1

Comment: This will also match `https://api.mongohq.com/abc` – not sure if that is the anticipated behavior: http://codepad.org/OvUFHdU8

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I updated my answer so that all characters behind the slash will be replaced, too

Comment: @Freeddy: I'm still not sure this is what the OP wants. But the question is not phrased 100 % correct and your answer got accepted, so maybe I'm assuming something wrong.

Answer (score 5):

`$` anchors regular expression patterns at the end of the string:

```
$public_url = preg_replace('#/$#', 'replace it!', $public_url);
```

Also possible:

```
$public_url = rtrim($public_url, '/').'replace it!';
```

Comment: This is what I get : `preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '$' in C:\Users\rgr\Apache\htdocs\Roland Groza [ 3.0 ]\class\mongohq\mongohq.php on line 230`

Comment: @Roland: It works for me. I don't get that error (with or without trailing slash): http://codepad.org/UMD5xpgA