# How to replace last backward slash with forward slash PHP

Tags: php, url

I want to replace my last `\` with `/` on this URL string

```
C:\wamp\www\chm-lib\sekhelp_out\HTML\AS_BUILD.htm
```

I have tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546373/replace-last-slash-in-string-php), but no changes, I am missing something, please correct me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using [PHP's string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php) instead of regex.

**Do this:**

```
$url = 'C:\wamp\www\chm-lib\sekhelp_out\HTML\AS_BUILD.htm';
$pos = strrpos($url, '\\');
$url = substr_replace($url, '/', $pos, 1);

echo $url;
```

**To get this:**

```
C:\wamp\www\chm-lib\sekhelp_out\HTML/AS_BUILD.htm
```

**Explanation:**

1. Get the position of the last `\` in the input string using [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)
2. Replace that with `/` using [`substr_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)

**Note**

It is important to pass `'\\'` instead of `'\'` to `strrpos()` as the first `\` [escapes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) the second.

Also note that you can shorten the code above to a single line if you prefer, but I thought it would be easier to understand as is. Anyway, here is the code as a one-liner function:

```
function reverseLastBackslash($url) {
    return substr_replace($url, '/', strrpos($url, '\\'), 1);
}
```

Comment: Ha, I just realized that the code was even more complicated than it had to be. I simplified it now, you might want to check the edit. (The previous version worked just fine, but was using `substr()` when it didn't need to)

Answer (score 2):

You can try exploding the string as an array and imploding after popping off the last part, and connecting it back with a forward slash.

```
$array = explode('\','C:\wamp\www\chm-lib\sekhelp_out\HTML\AS_BUILD.htm');
$last = array_pop($array);
$corrected = implode('\',$array) . '/' . $last;
```

Comment: Nice idea to use `explode()` / `implode()` here. Makes for a pretty clean solution. +1

Comment: Oh, by the way, *"The answer above"* now refers to a different answer as at the point of your writing, so you might want to change that reference.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash escaping is tricky:

```
preg_replace('/\\\\([^\\\\]*)$/', '/$1', "C:\\wamp\\www\\chm-lib\\sekhelp_out\\HTML\\AS_BUILD.htm")
```

You have to escape once for the literal string and once for the regular expression so a single `\` needs to be `\\\\` (1 x 2 x 2)

Answer (score -1):

Simply use this

```
 str_replace('\\','/','C:\wamp\www\chm-lib\sekhelp_out\HTML\AS_BUILD.htm');
```

Comment: this will replace all `\\`, need to change only last one.

Comment: ok if it isn't  dynamic then you can use 

str_replace('\\AS_BUILD','/AS_BUILD','C:\wamp\www\chm-lib\sekhelp_out\HTML\AS_BUILD.htm');