# preg_replace: add number after backreference

Tags: php, regex, escaping, backreference

**Situation**

I want to use `preg_replace()` to add a digit `'8'` after each of `[aeiou]`.

**Example**

*from*

```
abcdefghij
```

*to*

```
a8bcde8fghi8j
```

**Question**

How should I write the replacement string?

```
// input string
$in = 'abcdefghij';

// this obviously won't work ----------↓
$out = preg_replace( '/([aeiou])/', '\18',  $in);
```

---

This is **just an example**, so suggesting `str_replace()` is **not** a valid answer.
I want to know how to have number after backreference in the replacement string.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The solution is to wrap the backreference in `${}`.

```
$out = preg_replace( '/([aeiou])/', '${1}8',  $in);
```

which will output *a8bcde8fghi8j*

See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#example-4745) on this special case with backreferences.

Comment: Thanks; I should RTFM before asking next time.

Comment: Ok. Just promise to not give up on asking valid questions (like this one). We learn by questioning, and this time, I guess you got an answer 10x speedier than by trial-and-error. Someone is bound to know the solution... ;)

Comment: As a matter of fact, after posting it I went to php.net, and *found the answer*. I was already writing own answer when you spared me the shame of answering it myself ;)

Comment: Note the single quotes. `"${1}8"` does not work, because double quoted strings are parsed/interpreted in php and therefore the braces "disappear" disappear before the string is passed to the function.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
$out = preg_replace('/([aeiou])/', '${1}' . '8', $in);
```

[Here is a relevant quote from the docs regarding backreference:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

> When working with a replacement pattern where a backreference is immediately followed by another number (i.e.: placing a literal number immediately after a matched pattern), you cannot use the familiar \1 notation for your backreference. \11, for example, would confuse preg_replace() since it does not know whether you want the \1 backreference followed by a literal 1, or the \11 backreference followed by nothing. In this case the solution is to use \${1}1. This creates an isolated $1 backreference, leaving the 1 as a literal.