# Number after dollar sign in regex

Tags: php, regex

I have found out a code below

```
<?php $string = 'April 15, 2003'; 
$pattern = '/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+)/i'; 
$replacement = '${1}1,$3';
```

I just want to know why this 1 after ${1} is declaired and why the value 3 is assigned before the end of the string symbol ?

Comment: It's a regex token, `$3` is the third capturing group.

Comment: And the `1` is just a `1`.

Comment: Probably intent is to get 1st date of the given date. It should have been `$replacement = '${1} 1, $3';` to make it `'April 1, 2003'`

Comment: @anubhava i think 3 must be given before $ ?..because it act as a string right ?

Comment: `$3` is probably there for matched group #3 which is 2003 here.

Comment: and what about the 1 there ?..${1}1

Comment: `${1}` is used to avoid it being interpreted as `$11`

Comment: i just asked about the 1 which is given outside ?

Comment: You didn't get it. I was also talking about that. If it is written `$11` instead then how does the code know it is `'$1'.'1'` OR `$11`?

Comment: so is that $1 or $11 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you execute the code as it is, you get:

```
April1,2003
```

This is because you are delimiting the variable `$1` to separate it from what would be `$11`. [Here's more on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php).

If you change it, you get:

```
,2003
```

...because backreference `$11` doesn't exist.

Why is `$3` declared before the ending string symbol? Because it's part of the [`preg_replace` backreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027811/preg-replace-add-number-after-backreference). If you move it outside of the replacement string, you'll see it crash and burn.

**Footnote:** why you're replacing this with `<variable>1,<variable>` seems really odd. That `1` is static - in that it never changes. I'd be more inclined to think you'd want a replacement like `${1}${2},$3` which would return `April15,2003`.

Comment: can we write ${1}${2},${3} ?

Comment: Sure? No reason to in this case but you can.

Comment: thanks ..and in a question i have seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027811/preg-replace-add-number-after-backreference  something like aeiou ..is aeiuo replaced here ?..