# RegEx backreference followed by numbers

Tags: regex

How can I call a backreference and immediately follow it by numbers

I'm using the Sublime find&replace RegEx engine (Python) but the problem is the same in PHP:

**Example of the problem** (obv. neither of these work)

*Sublime:* `Find What: ([a-zA-Z]*)2013 Replace With: $12014`

*PHP:* `preg_replace('~([a-zA-Z]*)2013~', '$12014', $file_contents);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027811/preg-replace-add-number-after-backreference)

Turns out all I had to do was to wrap the back-reference in curly brackets

**Solution**

*Sublime*: `Find What: ([a-zA-Z]*)2013 Replace With: ${1}2014`

*PHP*: `preg_replace('~([a-zA-Z]*)2013~', '${1}2014', $file_contents);`