# PHP regex match last occurrences of the pattern matching

Tags: php, regex

I know there is a negative lookahead regex that can match last occurrences of the string.

Example: [replace last occurrences of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790761/how-to-replace-only-the-last-match-of-a-string-with-preg-replace)

I want to do something like this.

Example:

```
$string = 'hello example (a) hello example (b) (c)';
echo preg_replace('/\(.*?\)(?!.*\(.*?\))/', '', $string);
```

What I trying to do is to replace the last occurrences of (.*) but I failed. The output I got is **hello example**. It replaces the entire first ( and the last ) which is **(a) hello example (b) (c)**.

My expected out put is **hello example (a) hello example (b)**.

Any one can give some cue? What is the correct regex to achieve what I want. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a negated character class here instead of `.*?`.

The `.*` inside of your lookahead assertion will match all the way up to the last occurrence of `(...)` then backtrack consecutively keeping the succession order going.

```
preg_replace('/\([^)]*\)(?!.*\([^)]*\))/', '', $string);
```

To simplify this task, just retain everything up until the last occurrence instead.

```
preg_replace('/.*\K\(.*?\)/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. Do you mind to explain a little bit more? Why need to use negated character? How it works in this case? Thank you very much.

Comment: @hwnd - I tried to use it like this `preg_replace('/(?!\s+as\s+.*)/i', '', '(x as y) as z');` trying to get rid of the final " as..." (expected result = '`(x as y)'` -- but it does not replace anything. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Youre mistake is using `\(.*\)` it's replace full substring which begins whith `(` and ends whith `)`. `.*` - max quantificator, `(.*)` - min quantificator.

Try to use:

`$string = 'hello example (a) hello example (b) (c)';
echo preg_replace('/\((.*)\)$/', '', $string);`