# Python/Regex - match char between two chars, with anything before or after the matching char

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match a char within a subset of chars, where either side of the matching char could be anything.

heres an example:

```
{{ SITE_AGGREGATE_SUBNET }}.3 remote-as {{ BGP-AS }}
```

against the above, I want to match anything between {{ and }} that has a dash "-" in it.

my regex pattern thus far is:

```
(?<={{)(.*?-.*?)(?=}})
```

but this is creating a match for the whole test string returning:

```
SITE_AGGREGATE_SUBNET }}.3 remote-as {{ BGP-AS
```

Is anyone able to see what I'm missing? I understand why my regex doesn't work as expected but not how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
import re
s = '{{ SITE_AGGREGATE_SUBNET }}.3 remote-as {{ BGP-AS }}'
print([x.strip() for x in re.findall(r'{{(.*?)}}', s) if '-' in x])
// -> ['BGP-AS']
```

See [the Python demo](https://ideone.com/TS9kxW)

**Details**

- Extract all matches between `{{...}}` with a mere `{{(.*?)}}` regex (note that `re.findall` will only return the captured substing, the value matched with `(.*?)`)
- Only keep the matches with `-` in them using a condition inside list comprehension (`if '-' in x`)
- Remove trailing/leading whitespace with `.strip()`

A single regex approach (note it might turn out less efficient):

```
re.findall(r'{{\s*((?:(?!{{|}})[^-])*-.*?)\s*}}', s)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fuWkab)

**Details**

- `{{` - `{{`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `((?:(?!{{|}})[^-])*-.*?)` - Capturing group 1 (what will be returned by `re.findall`):

  - `(?:(?!{{|}})[^-])*` - a [**tempered greedy token**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) matching any non-hyphen char, 0+ times, that does not start a `{{` and `}}` substrings
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars (other than an LF), as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `}}` - `}}`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mkxbhA/1)

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex with a negative lookahead and a capture group:

```
({{(?:(?!{{|}})[^-])*)-(.*?}})
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8VRsFD/6/)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(`: Start capture group

  - `{{`: Match `{{`
  - `(?:`: Start non-capture group

    - `(?{{|!}})`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have `{{` and `}}` at next position
    - `[^-]`: Match any character except hyphen
  - `)*`: End non-capture group. `*` matches 0+ instances of this group
- `)`: End capture group
- `-`: Match literal hyphen
- `(.*?}})`: Match remaining string up to `}}` and then match `}}` and capture this in 2nd capture group

Comment: This will match the text up to the dash, but the OP asks for the whole string inside the double-brackets, as long as said string contains a dash

Comment: @anubhava.. can you tell me a good ref to start off with regex?

Comment: @DudeCoder: Start with https://www.regular-expressions.info/ a great site to learn regex

Comment: @anubhava.. thanks for that.. but is it that site where you started learning regex?

Comment: I started learning regex in pre-internet days by learning from Automata books :)

Comment: Cool, thats amazing

Comment: This solution may match [`{{  {{ BGP-AS }}`](https://regex101.com/r/8VRsFD/5). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51025516/3832970) with the right solution.

Comment: For nested case of `{{` and `}}` this regex can be easily changed to `({{(?:(?!{{|}})[^-])*)-(.*?}})`

Comment: Yes, it is my solution. Though I am using capturing group in a way for the `re.findall` to return only the contents inside the braces. And since I use `\s*`, that value is stripped off leading/trailing whitespace chars.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern: `{{(.*?)}}`.

- `.*?` matches any stream of character non-greedily.
- `(...)` creates a capturing group so `re.findall` yields the inside of the brackets.

To check if the match contains a `'-'`, it might be simpler to then use `in`.

### Code

```
import re

def tokenize(s):
    return [w.strip() for w in re.findall('{{(.*?)}}', s) if '-' in w]

print(tokenize('{{ SITE_AGGREGATE_SUBNET }}.3 remote-as {{ BGP-AS }}'))
```

### Output

```
['BGP-AS']
```